# Signals and systems convolution problem?

Tags: electrical-engineering, mathematics, signal

hey guys I'm having trouble with a convolution problem here

A continuous-time linear system has the input/output relationship

$$\int_{-\infty}^t (t-\lambda-2)  x(\lambda) d{\lambda}$$

For $1 ≤ t ≤ 2$, determine the output y(t) arising from the input $x(t) = u(t)−2u(t−1)$

So the graph is going to be something like this right

[image]

(probably ignore the axis labels it's wrong I know; I'm just providing a sketch for the $x(\lambda)$ function)

I'm really confused about how to proceed

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to mathematics.SE